# sum column in datatable vb.net 2010

Tags: vb.net, datatable, sum

I am trying to get the sum of the column `TotalAmount` in my `DataTable` `dt` but I always get this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I am using VB in Visual Studio 2012.

Here's the code:

```
Dim table As DataTable = CartDataSet.Tables("dt")
Dim result As Integer
result = table.Compute("SUM(TotalAmount)", "")
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/1402846

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim result As Object
result = table.Compute("SUM(TotalAmount)", "")
```

then do result.ToString() you will get your output

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to de-reference a NULL object reference, which means `table` is `NULL`.

That in turn, means `CartDataSet` does not contain a table named `"dt"`

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim dt As DataTable = TajDataSet.Tables("MAtab")
Dim sum As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("SUM(ServiceCharge)", String.Empty))
SCC.Text = sum.ToString
```

Comment: Couly you please destribe your code instead oj just typing some code lines

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq, like this.

```
Dim result As Decimal = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(Function(row) row.Field(Of Decimal)("TotalAmount"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible Issues

- Table is null
- No records in the table

Solutions:

1- Better to check the datatable status before computation like

```html
If Not table Is Nothing AndAlso table.Rows.Count > 0 Then
...
End If
```

2- Check for DBNULL while computing in case no records

```html
IIf(IsDBNull(table.Compute("SUM(TotalAmount)", "")), "0", table.Compute("SUM(TotalAmount)", ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

For the ".Compute" function to work, you have to declare your variable "result" as "object" instead of "integer".  Then later you can convert the value in "result" to an integer using "Convert.ToInt".

```
Dim result as object
```

Answer (score 0):

Dim table As DataTable = CartDataSet.Tables("dt")

Dim result As Integer

result = IIf(IsDBNull(dtable.Compute("SUM(TotalAmount)",""),0,dtable.Compute("SUM(TotalAmount)", ""))